# JPA Query Select many-to-one Query with a count

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-1.x

So I'm trying to write a JPA query based on the classes below (dumbed down a bit) that will produce the following:

So I have two objects: Thing and Person. A Person can hold a reference to a single Thing. Here are simplified version of the Classes:

```
public class Thing {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
}

public class Person {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    @ManyToOne
    public Thing thing;
}
```

I'm trying to write a JPA query that will give me all the details of every Thing object as well as the number of times that Thing object is referenced by a Person object. Note that a Person could have the value null for Thing. Also a Thing object might not be referenced by any Person object at all but should still be listed.

So given the following tables:

```
Thing Table
| id | name | description |
|  1 | thg1 | a thing     |
|  2 | thg2 | another one |
|  3 | thg3 | one more    |

Person Table
| id | firstname | lastname | thing |
|  1 | John      | Smith    |     1 |
|  2 | Simon     | Doe      |     3 |
|  3 | Anne      | Simmons  |     1 |
|  4 | Jessie    | Smith    |     1 |
|  5 | Adam      | Doe      |     3 |
|  6 | Phil      | Murray   |  null |
```

I would end up with a result like:

```
| id | name | description | amount |
|  1 | thg1 | a thing     |      3 |
|  2 | thg2 | another one |      2 |
|  3 | thg3 | one more    |      0 |
```

How would I go about writing that JPA Query? (If it makes a difference I'm using the Play Framework 1.2.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.description, count(p) as amount
         from Person as p right join p.thing as t group by t.id
```

The reason for the unusual "right join" is that JPA queries requires mappings between query classes and you only have one from `Person` to `Thing`.

If you had a mapping from `Thing` to `Person`:

```
class Thing {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    Set<Person> persons;
}
```

you could use the classic "left join":

```
select t.id, t.name, t.description, count(p) as amount
             from Thing as t left join t.persons as p group by t.id
```

Comment: Thanks @dcernahoschi that right join worked for me. I realise the relationship mapping isn't exactly perfect, but unfortunately it's ingrained in the app at this point. Perhaps I'll get around to re-writing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If I am writing a pure JPQL and setting Entity relationship then I would go like this:

```
public class Thing {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    @OneToMany
    public Collection<Person> personList;

}

public class Person {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
}
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT t from Thing {WHERE watever condition you may have}
```

Iteration:

```
Collection<Thing> thingList = query.getResultList();

System.out.println("| id | name | description | amount |");
for(Thing thing:thingList){
System.out.format("|  %s | %s | %s    |      %s |%n", thing.getId(), thing.getName(), thing.getDescription(), thing.getPersonList().size());
}
```